# Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler - Please help me wrap my brain around this

Tags: .net, task

I am working on an application that will have a background process running for quite a while and I want to report progress to the UI.  I want to use Tasks in .Net 4.0 so that I gain a working understanding of them.  I found a wonderful article by Stephen Cleary that shows this and includes a class, ProgressReporter (article link at the bottom).

I could just take the class and use it as-is, but then I don't own the knowledge.  The part that I simply cannot understand is regarding the TaskScheduler object.  I have read the documentation, but it makes the assumption that I already know what a Scheduler is and I don't, actually.

From Stephen's article it appears that if I create a TaskScheduler, using "FromCurrentSynchronizationContext", from the event that's about to kick off the background task, then I can use that TaskScheduler instance from within the async process to create a new task that will then have access to UI controls and will, in fact, be running on the UI thread.

At least that's what it looks like from the clean, elegant code.

Can someone help me understand what a TaskScheduler (or just a Scheduler) is so that the "FromCurrentSynchronizationContext" makes sense?

Thanks so much!

Link to article referenced:
http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, understand that a `Task` by itself has no relation to the `ThreadPool`. It helps to think of a `Task` as a unit of work, nothing more. It's actually just a fancy delegate.

A `TaskScheduler` is something that can run a `Task`. The default `TaskScheduler` runs `Task`s on the `ThreadPool`, but that's not the only `TaskScheduler` around. You can call `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` to get a `TaskScheduler` that runs `Task`s on a UI thread.

The ParallelExtensionsExtras library includes several interesting `TaskScheduler`s. For details, see posts 5, 6, and 7 in [this series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx).

So, to come back to my `ProgressReporter` class, what I'm doing is this:

- The `ProgressReporter` is created on the UI thread, and it captures the `TaskScheduler` that will run `Task`s on the UI thread.
- You then run a background `Task` (where "background" means that it's running on the default `TaskScheduler` - on the `ThreadPool`).
- When the background `Task` wants to report progress, it creates a *new* `Task` and sends it to the UI `TaskScheduler`.

I should point out that the [Async CTP](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=204842) uses a slightly different approach. They recommend that tasks needing to report progress take an `IProgress<T>` argument (which is a great idea). Then they provide an implementation (`EventProgress<T>`), which raises an event on a captured `SynchronizationContext`. Using `EventProgress<T>` is similar to my `ProgressReporter` with two important differences:

- The `IProgress<T>` approach has the *consumer* define the response to the progress update. My `ProgressReporter` has the *producer* (the background operation) define the response to the progress update.
- `IProgress<T>` will return immediately, allowing the background operation to continue. `ProgressReporter` by default will wait until the UI has been updated.

The `IProgress<T>` is the better design, because of the first point (though I'm of the opinion that `ProgressReporter` is more correct in making the progress reporting synchronous). `ProgressReporter` was fine for the time, and it's OK for banging out some quick code, but if you're designing a reusable background component, use something similar to `IProgress<T>`.

If you aren't familiar with the Async CTP, I highly recommend checking it out. It's not ready for production use yet, but you should at least read the "Task-based Asynchronous Pattern" paper. It shows where things are going, and is a well-thought-out approach to designing APIs that use `Task`s.

P.S. There are a couple of simplifications I made above:

- `Task`s are really just a unit of work, not even a "fancy delegate". In fact, the unit of work may actually be done by *another program*, in which case there is no delegate attached to the `Task` object at all. You can create these abstract "units of work" by using the `TaskCompletionSource` class.
- I didn't go into what a `SynchronizationContext` is or why it's used to schedule work to the UI. In essence, it's a "delegate scheduler" - if you consider a delegate as a "unit of work", a `SynchronizationContext` can be used to run delegates. More information will be in the MSDN February issue next week.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen.  This helps tremendously and I'll read the articles you reference.